# Java Script Canvas. JS. Как поучить цвет точки с фоновой фотографии?

Tags: javascript

Есть некий холст с градиентом или с какой-то фотографией.
С помощью мышки я ставлю метку-квадратик на этом холсте.
Вопрос, как мне получить цвет фото под каждой точкой-пометкой на холсте?

Может быть я конечно делаю ерунду и это реализуется как-то по-другому. Но мне нужно взять фото, расставить точки и получить цвет в этих точках и сохранить его для дальнейших вычислений. Это что-то вроде пипетки. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Я пока только соорудила холст и возможность ставить на холсте метки.

Коды ниже.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c1'); // получим canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "red";

// Рисовать по нажатию клавиши мыши. Здесь будет орисаван один прямоугольник при каждом нажатии.
canvas.onmousemove = function(event) {
  canvas.onmousedown = function(event) {
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

```css
#c1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
  background-image: url(https://hsto.org/files/c16/1ef/74a/c161ef74a25c4bbbb9ffff96f1d50bd0.jpg);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

С фоновой никак не получится. Сначала надо отрендерить картинку в канвасе.
Потом с помощью [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) можно получить цвет по заданным координатам:

getImageData возвращает [массив](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data), в котором лежат цвета пикселей в таком формате:
`[r,g,b,alpha, r,g,b,alpha, r,g,b,alpha]`, по 4 элемента массива на каждый пиксель.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "red";

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'https://hsto.org/files/c16/1ef/74a/c161ef74a25c4bbbb9ffff96f1d50bd0.jpg';
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

canvas.onmousemove = function(event) { 
    canvas.onmousedown = function(event) {
        var x = event.offsetX; 
        var y = event.offsetY;
        const rgba = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        console.log(x,y, rgba);
        
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

```css
#c1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Из за cors сниппет не работает, [вот тут](http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1/) можно посмотреть в живую (и заодно посмотреть, как из imageData сделать hex значение цвета)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Здорово! Все показывает!