# Пипетка на js , для картинок

Tags: javascript

Видел кто то или делал пипетку для изображений на js ? есть изображение(пусть разноцветное) , и нужно допустим узнать какого цвета там больше чем другого или какой основной. Буду благодарен плагинам, идеям...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692398/java-script-canvas-js-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8/692408#692408